# Composer not updating package (grabbing it from repo.magento.com instead of packagist)

Tags: magento2, composer, marketplace

My package (https://packagist.org/packages/limesharp/stockists) is not getting updated when running composer update (it's currently stuck at 1.0.5 instead of grabbing 1.0.11).

On a closer look at the composer.lock file I see that the repo url is `repo.magento.com` instead of packagist. (https://repo.magento.com/archives/limesharp/stockists/limesharp-stockists-1.0.5.0.zip).

I don't understand why is that, maybe because I submitted a version to the marketplace and the first url composer checks is https://repo.magento.com/ and then the packagist repo.

If that is the case, can something be done about it? Can you update the https://repo.magento.com/ without submitting the extension to the marketplace every time a bug is fixed (takes days to be approved).

Comment: This is probably not related to Magento but to composer, take a look at this https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it seems to be a composer problem. https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Composer will always check Packagist as last and thus *repo.magento.com* will be checked before Packagist.

You could add the GitHub URL of your package above the Magento repository in your `"repositories"` section of your ***project's `composer.json`***:

```
{
    "require": {
        "magento/product-community-edition": "~2.1.0",
        "limesharp/stockists": "~1.0.11"
    }
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "git",
            "url": "https://github.com/ClaudiuCreanga/magento2-store-locator-stockists-extension.git"
        },
        {
            "type": "composer",
            "url": "https://repo.magento.com/"
        }
    ]
}
```

This way, the direct GitHub URL will be checked first, then *repo.magento.com* and then Packagist.

P.S. Defining `"repositories"` is not possible in any package (not only on Magento Marketplace), see the [Composer documentation on the repositories property](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#repositories), it states it is ***root only***, so only allowed in your ***project's `composer.json`***. If you do define repositories in your package' `composer.json` it will be ignored.

Comment: Thanks, but the `repositories` field is banned and you cannot use it in the marketplace. That's my issue from the comment.

Comment: you wouldn't do that in the *modules* composer.json but in your *root* composer.json (i.e. the Magento project that uses your module). Marketplace has no authority in your project ;)

Comment: Updated the answer to reflect this ;)

Comment: @fschmengler, Thanks, now it is somewhat clearer but this doesn't solve my issue because if I do that then it will be only for me. I want all the users of my module to get updates from packagist: https://github.com/ClaudiuCreanga/magento2-store-locator-stockists-extension/blob/master/composer.json So if they do `composer require limesharp/stockists` they look at packagist not at repo.magento where it takes 4 days and counting to upload a new version to fix a bug.

Comment: @ClaudiuCreanga this is not possible, unless users would specify the version: `composer require limesharp/stockists:~1.0.11`. I did not test this though, but I assume Composer would not find this version on repo.magento.com and it WILL find it on Packagist and take that one. You could also just remove your module from Marketplace ;)

Comment: yes, if I specify the composer version then it will look at packagist and it will update. Thanks then. this sucks, better stick only to packagist.